# Facciamo tornare i conti su "tornare"

Tags: word-meaning, history

Tra i vari significati del verbo *tornare* in Italiano, ve n'è uno peculiare:

> **tornare** v. intr. e tr. [lat. *tornare* «lavorare al tornio, far girare sul tornio», der. di *tornus* «tornio»] [...] **d.** Risultare esatto o preciso, giusto, coerente o chiaro: *calcolate esattamente le spese, il conto torna*
>
> *(Dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tornare/))*

Questo è un significato molto comune, come si può vedere da numerose espressioni: *tornaconto*, *c'è qualcosa che non torna*, etc.

Però, riflettendo sul significato letterale ed etimologico del verbo *tornare*, quest'uso non ha davvero senso.

> **Q:** Da dove deriva quest'espressione, che non sembra avere niente a che fare con il significato "originale" del verbo?

Comment: Ipotesi a orecchio: c'entrerà forse sempre il tornio, ma negli altri sensi prevale semplicemente il fatto che gira, e quindi fa “tornare (indietro)”, ruotare di 180° (anche molti di più, invero), mentre nel senso di cui parliamo si riferisce il lavoro preciso che si può fare con un tornio rispetto a plasmare qualcosa a mano? Cf. anche il verbo “tornire”.

Comment: A me torna. Un calcolo fornisce, o rende, un risultato. In particolare torna un risultato se questo è coerente. Mi torna nel senso che mi restituisce indietro un risultato o una situazione coerente o attendibile date le condizioni di partenza.